# MySQL Making every Nth Cloumn a new row

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's what I'm trying to do. I want to look at, based on a certain price and cost, what will my profit be. Here's an example:

```
SELECT price, cost, profit, 
price-5 "price1", cost, price-5-cost "profit1"  
FROM table
WHERE product = blue_pants;
```

This spits out the data like this:

```
price cost profit price1 cost profit1
```

And I'd like it to be like this:

```
price  cost profit
price1 cost profit1
```

It's just the way the data is displayed I'm after. Does that make sense? Is there a way to do this. Sorry, I'm a SQL noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select price, cost, profit
From table
Where product = 'blue_pants'
Union All
Select price-5, cost, price-5-cost
From table
Where product = 'blue_pants'
```

This will obviously repeat rows. In order to know which rows should appear in the first query and which in the second, we would need to know the criteria (e.g. `Where price-5 > 0`).

Comment: UNION ALL is what I needed. Thanks!